# En los paquetes de python, ¿qué son y para sirven los metodos que estan entre guiones bajos. Ej: __name__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulos

Estoy aprendiendo a usar paquetes en python y cuando pongo:

```
print(dir(*el nombre de algún paquete*)
```

siempre aparecen metodos entre giones bajos: __

Me gustaria saber que funcion cumplen esos metodos dentro de los paquetes.

Comment: Lo que estas imprimiendo es lo que devuelve la funcion dir(), y que devuelve? una lista de atributos validos del objeto pasado por parametros. Y que estas pasando por parametros a dir, un string un objeto un numero? en todo caso estas imprimiendo las propiedades de ese objeto, los metodos como __contains__ y __setAtrr__ son comunes a todos los objetos y lo que estas viendo probablemente sea eso. Agrega mas detalles.

Comment: Todo objeto en python (incluyendo los módulos) tienen una serie de [_métodos especiales_ o métodos mágicos_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) que definen su comportamiento, también llamado _"protocolo"_. En el caso de un paquete, estos nombres también indican metadatos del paquete: nombre del paquete, versión, ruta en disco, información, datos spec, etc.

Comment: Revisa la documentación de Python, allí están muy bien explicados. Pero en resumen son métodos especiales que se usan internamente en determinados escenarios (por ejemplo, \_\_getattribute\_\_ se usa cuando se accede a un atributo desde una instancia, y \_\_contains\_\_ se usa cuando usas el operador in)